# Multi Source Code File in 1 Project With C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, console-application

I am new in C#. Usually, i use VB.NET. If i use VB.NET to make console application, i can add multi source code file in 1 project with this step :

1. Project - Add New Module
2. Write `Sub Main()` to the source code
3. Goto project property, set startup object to the new module
4. Then new program created

How to do this in c# ?

Comment: You can make multiple classes with their own `Main()`s.

Comment: @SLaks I found the answer. I set **Startup object** to not **(Not Set)**. If i don't set it, it will error when i press F5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
First, when i make console app with C#, the default will show **Program.cs**
Then i add new item from **Project~Add New Item**, choose **Code File** and write the name, then **Add**. After that, new blank source code file show. I copy paste all source code from Program.cs to my new blank source code. Then i change the name of the class. So, i have 2 source code now.

The last and very important is change **Startup object** from **(Not Set)** to **Other Item**. If not change, it will show error *Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.*

Comment: Why would you change the startup object instead of simply modifying the code in the existing Program.cs?  What you should have done - what everyone else does - is simply added a class to your project (right-click the project in Solution Explore and select Add > Class or select Add Class from the Project menu) and then added whatever code you wanted there.  You can then modify the existing `Main` method in the `Program` class to invoke the code in the class you created.